# Can't delete duplicate images from magento admin

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento website which gets the product data and images updated via the API. There are two store views set up, with the same products but differing pricing.
For some reason images aren't being by the API script so I end up with duplicates sometimes. I can't manually delete them from the admin side either.
I corrected the problem once before using a database fix I found online but I can't remember what tables the fix targeted and I can't find it again.
All I know is that is something to do with the two stores being slightly different.
Has anyone else had this issue or point me in the right direction as to what database tables to edit to correct this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking further I found what I was after. I needed to edit the catalogue_product_entity_x tables (where x is int, decimal, datetime, int and varchar) remove entries for the second store, thereby making Magento use the default values.
I also had a third store, a relic from the initial set up, that I deleted. That may have had an impact but I didn't need to do that the first time I had this problem.
I found the solution here: [SO link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33339/reset-use-default-value-for-specific-store-view-on-all-products)
but here are the db commands for easy reference:
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` where store_id = 2;
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` where store_id = 2;
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` where store_id = 2;
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` where store_id = 2;
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` where store_id = 2;

- changing the store_id to the relevant id of course.

Thanks.

EDIT:
This is only a partial solution. While it does correct the issue of the second store by resetting the images thereby allowing me to delete them, if you do the sql statements above everything defaults to the default store. So if you have differing prices or any other data it will start showing the default values on the second store rather than data that it should show.
The better solution, if you're forced to go down this path would be to just run the sql statements for the images only.
if I figure this out I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for that:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/remove-duplicate-product-image.html

Also here is a little script to find and delete all duplicate images in Magento:

```
include(‘app/Mage.php’);
//Mage::App(‘default’);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);
ob_implicit_flush (1);
$mediaApi = Mage::getModel(“catalog/product_attribute_media_api”);
$_products = Mage::getModel(‘catalog/product’)->getCollection();
$i =0;
$total = count($_products);
$count = 0;
foreach($_products as $_prod)
{
$_product = Mage::getModel(‘catalog/product’)->load($_prod->getId());
$_md5_values = array();
//protected base image
$base_image = $_product->getImage();
if($base_image != ‘no_selection’)
{
$filepath = Mage::getBaseDir(‘media’) .’/catalog/product’ . $base_image ;
if(file_exists($filepath))
$_md5_values[] = md5(file_get_contents($filepath));
}
$i ++;
echo “\r\n processing product $i of $total “;
// Loop through product images
$_images = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
if($_images){
foreach($_images as $_image){
//protected base image
if($_image->getFile() == $base_image)
continue;
$filepath = Mage::getBaseDir(‘media’) .’/catalog/product’ . $_image->getFile() ;
if(file_exists($filepath))
$md5 = md5(file_get_contents($filepath));
else
continue;
if(in_array($md5, $_md5_values))
{
$mediaApi->remove($_product->getId(), $_image->getFile());
echo “\r\n removed duplicate image from “.$_product->getSku();
$count++;
} else {
$_md5_values[] = $md5;
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but the issue isn't how to delete the duplicates but that I can't delete them. API calls to remove the media, manual attempts in the admin panel and running scripts like the one you mention don't persist their changes.